# Use USB D-/D+ only on USB 3.0 IC

Tags: usb, usb-hub

I want to design a USB hub 3.0 with only D- and D+ data pins (So I wont implement the USB 3 functionality). I chose [CYUSB3328](https://gr.mouser.com/datasheet/2/100/CYPR_S_A0010592712_1-2541070.pdf) IC for this job.

(The reason I do not use a USB 2.0 for this, is because I could not find USB 2.0 Super Speed with more than four Ports. Plus, I might need the extra power USB 3.0 supplies)

So I started checking if it is actually possible: to not use the TX, RX pins on a USB 3.0 IC.

From [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/107743/252145) I understand that I can only wire that D+ and D- pins, and it will drop to USB 2.0 speed, but I am not happy from that reply, as the question was more general: "reducing the wires of a USB 3.0 wire to make it thinner".

So the question is: To make only D+/D- USB connector communication, do I only need to wire the D+ and D- pins of the IC, and leave the Rx, TX pins floating on both Downstream and upstream sides?

Pictures from the datasheet for upstream/downstream ports pin descriptions:

Upstream:

[image: Upstream]

Downstream for Port 1 (all other Downstream ports are the same):

[image: Downstream CYUSB3328]

So my end result will be this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2DtWJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Will the above schematic connection allow me to use only the D- and D+ pins to communicate, or Do I actually need to use a USB 2.0 for this?

Comment: I'm confused. You write about only using D+ & D-, but then in your snapshots from the CYUSB33xx manual you've crossed those pins out and say you're not using USB2 ... Which is it? Either you're using D+/D- and therefore you're using USB2 or you're not using D+/D- and therefore you must be using the TX/RX pairs for USB3.

Comment: There's also (afaik) no such thing as "USB 2.0 Super Speed". "Super Speed" is a USB 3 feature. USB 2 only goes up to "High Speed" 480Mbps.

Comment: @brhans Oh so these "D+ and D-" that I crossed out, I am supposed to use them? I was thinking that some of these "US_RXP, US_TXM" would be used as D+ and D- instead! To your second comment: hm.. How come some USB laptops have 'SS' when using USB 2.0 ports?

Comment: The D+ & D- lines are the bidirectional pair used for USB1 & USB2 Low/Full/High-Speed communication. The TX+/- and RX+/- are the unidirectional pairs used for USB3 Super-Speed communication. What makes you think that any particular laptop has a USB2 port labelled 'SS'? I've seen laptops with a mix of USB2 and USB3 ports where the USB3 ports are labelled with 'SS' and the USB2 ports are not...

Comment: Okay I think I get it better now. My laptop has a port labeled "SS", but has only 2 data lines. That is what I want to do. SS speed with two data lines. So, my laptop uses USB 3.X with Tx+ and Rx+ on these two data lines? (and possibly having the Tx-/Rx- connected together to GND

Comment: No it doesn't - that's not how USB3 Super-Speed works. 2 Lines means USB2 High-Speed is the fastest that port will go. If it claims USB3 SS, then it must have the additional TX & RX pairs.

Comment: @ChristianidisVasileios: Are you confusing USB 3.0 Type A connector with USB 3.1-3.2 Type C connector, and thinking the first has only D+/D-?  That's not correct.  A Type A USB 3.0 connector doesn't have the extra copy of TX/RX pairs that make the connector reversible... but it does have the first copy of TX/RX in addition to D+/D-

Comment: Digikey has USB 2 hub controllers with more than 4 ports in stock, so the whole premise of this question seems wrong. If you only need USB2, buy a USB2 controller.

Comment: @user1850479 the comments and answers here helped me understand the usb 2.0/3.X hubs better. The question is overall helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a quick overview of USB speeds and standards:

| Speed | Data Rate | USB Standard | Required data lines |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Low speed | 1.5 Mbit/s | USB 1.0 and higher | D+/D- |
| Full speed | 12 Mbit/s | USB 1.0 and higher | D+/D- |
| High speed | 480 Mbit/s | USB 2.0 and higher | D+/D- |
| SuperSpeed | 5 Gbit/s | USB 3.0 and higher | D+/D-, SSRX+/SSRX-, SSTX+/SSTX- |
| SuperSpeed+ | 10 Gbit/s | USB 3.1 and higher | D+/D-, SSRX+/SSRX-, SSTX+/SSTX- |

There is also USB 3.2 and 4.0, which have been omitted for simplicity.

As you can see, you are restricted to *High speed* if you only connect the D+ and D- data lines.

For *SuperSpeed*, you need to connect the two additional data pairs and you need different USB receptacles (see [Receptacle (socket) identification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#Receptacle_(socket)_identification) for details). Either:

- SuperSpeed version of Type-A (usually colored in blue) with 9 contacts
- SuperSpeed version of Micro A (which looks like a Micro A receptacle with an extension)
- Type-C receptacle

Your PC most likely has a SuperSpeed Type-A receptacle, which has 4 contacts in the front and 5 additional ones that are difficult to spot.

Thus, the main question is not how to connect the CYUSB3328 but rather whether USB high speed is sufficient for your application.

Comment: *Your PC most likely has a SuperSpeed Type-A receptacle, which has 4 contacts in the front and 5 additional ones that are difficult to spot* Yes thats it, Makes sense now!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I will try, based on your comments and @Codo's answer:

Just like my Laptop has, a USB 3.0 port which is like that:

[image: SS usb]

[Image source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:USB_3_Pins_static.jpg)

The 5 pins were hard to spot, so I could not see that this 9-pin connector was there, and it can accept both 9-pin (usb 3) connections and USB 2.0 connections.

So this is the kind of connector I want to make!

I will come back with the results, thank you all.